# Electron, D3.js and Angular. Need to create an offline chart application

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, electron

I've been tasked at work to create a charting application that will function offline. I've been thrown into the fire with this one as I'm a junior dev and ill be doing this by myself.

I've been trying to research the best way to get this done and I'm thinking Electron is the best for the offline functionality and d3.js for the charts. I wanted to use Angular for the work experience.

Before I begin developing this, I wanted to test and see if this made any sense. I found this repo and tried publishing it with Electron.

https://github.com/datencia/d3js-angular-examples

None of the charts show up however.

So I'm sort of in a rough place because there's no one at work I can ask about this. Does this stack make sense? Can I use D3.js offline with Electron?

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: D3 is just a library that helps to create charts/visualizations. There are no requirements around Internet connectivity for the library (same goes for Angular).

Comment: as long as you can load D3.js from a local disk or local web server and you can get your data from local web server or hard coded in source there is no problem. What do you mean with "offline"?\

Comment: The app is expected to function fully without any internet connectivity. The data for the charts in the project I linked is all hard coded in. Guess Ill have to deal with the problem if it arises when I make my project.